# Проблема с вебхуком

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram, webhook

Создаю телеграм бот с помощью telegram api. Пытаюсь реализовать вебхук, запилила на азур, но бот сопротивляется, не хочет отвечать. Борюсь второй день, не знаю в чем дело. Может кто-то имел дело с такой проблемой?

Вот респонз на getWebhookInfo (почему-то неправильный ответ от вебхука)

```
{"ok":true,"result":{"url":"https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net:443/api/messages/update","has_custom_certificate":false,"pending_update_count":1,"last_error_date":1594119210,"last_error_message":"Wrong response from the webhook: 404 Not Found","max_connections":40}}
```

Вот метод с пост запросом

```
[Route("api/messages/update")]
public class MessageController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<OkResult> Post([FromBody] Update update)
    {
        if (update == null) return Ok();
        Console.WriteLine(update.ToString());
        var commands = Bot.Commands;
        var message = update.Message;
        var botClient = await Bot.GetBotClientAsync();

        foreach (var command in commands)
        {
            if (command.Contains(message))
            {
                await command.Execute(message, botClient);
                break;
            }
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```